# What is "echo ${#names[3]} ${#names[@]}" doing after defining "names=(apples [3]=orange tomatoe)"?

Tags: bash, command

can anyone explain to me how I should be reading/understanding this command

Here, I'm not sure I understand what `[3]` means/does

```
names=(apples [3]=orange tomatoe)
```

here we call names twice, what is `[3]` and `[@]`?

```
echo ${#names[3]} ${#names[@]}
```

The output is 6 3 . I don't understand, if someone has time to explain or point me towards the correct man page, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

The first part demonstrates the general assignment syntax for arrays. The simple form,

```
$ names=(apples oranges tomatoe)
$ echo "${!names[@]}"   # Show the indices defined for the array
0 1 2
```

assigns each element to consecutive integer indices starting with 0. If an index is explicitly given, that index is used instead, and subsequent values are assigned consecutively from there. Shell arrays don't have to be contiguous; your example leaves `${names[1]}` and `${names[2]}` undefined.

```
$ names=(apples [3]=orange tomatoe)
$ echo "${!names[@]}"
0 3 4
```

In the second case, you are using the parameter length operator. The first one tells you the length of the `${names[3]}`:

```
$ echo "${#names[3]}"   # orange has 6 characters
6
```

The second one, with `@` as the index, tells you the length of the *array*, i.e., how many *values* are in the array.

```
$ echo "${#names[@]}"
3
$ printf '%s\n' "${names[@]}"
apples
orange
tomatoe
```

Comment: Nicely explained! I always find very educational to also show `for key in ${!myarr[@]}; do    echo "myarr[$key] = ${myarr[$key]}"; done` together with its output to see graphically what index corresponds to each value.

Comment: wow, thanks the light has come on! great explanation. Thank you!